HPC and ggsave - unable to open connection to X11 display
I am running code on a HPC to generate plots using ggplot2. However, when attempting to save the plots with ggsave(), I encounter the following warnings:

Error in .External2(C_X11, paste0("png::", filename), g$width,
g$height,  :    unable to start device PNG Calls: ggsave -> dev ->
png_dev In addition: Warning message: In png_dev(..., res = dpi, units
= "in") :   unable to open connection to X11 display '' Execution halted

A file is created in the destination directory but it does not open (see screenshot)

Could anyone help with resolving this issue?
My code is available for your reference:
data(mtcars)
library(ggplot2)
plot <- ggplot(data = mtcars) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = hp, y = mpg))
ggsave(
  filename = "/home/aubsxb003/mtcars.png", # file name
  plot = plot, # object to save to file
  width = 1920, # image width
  height = 1080, # image height
  units = "px", # units used for image width and height
  dpi = 300, # set desired resolution
  bg = "white" # background color
)


How do you run this code? Interactively or by submitting a batch job? In either case, specify the command line you use to execute this script.

@katia I submit a batch job using the sbatch command.

The problem is mostly likely related to how R was installed on your system. Try to run R interactively and execute the following function: capabilities(). Check if the output contains TRUE or FALSE of the png column.
